# Create MySQL Table from existing tables and SUM duplicate inventory table

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, sum

I have Three tables

*Parts ; Price ; Inventory*

Each table has an ambiguous "part_number" column

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I need to CREATE a TABLE *Catalog* from the Three tables-

with these headers from the *Parts* table:
"part_number", "part_details", "part_description"

and INCLUDE the "sale_price" column from the *Price* table
and also the "qty" column from the *Inventory* table

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

(MY PROBLEM)

The *Inventory* table has multiple rows with the same "part_number" with different "qty"

I need to SUM the "qty" column of the duplicate "part_number" rows
and INSERT the return value into the new *Catalog* table "qty" column which contains every unique "part_number" available.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I'm open to change the "part_number" column in each table to avoid ambiguity issues.

Doing this in Excel is no problem, but I really want to get this to work through MySQL. I can do this manually each time through MySQL, but it would also be helpful to create some kind of Cron job to update this new 'Catalog' table daily as I already am working on a way to update my Three tables daily directly from the MySQL plugin in Excel.

First time posting a question here. Sorry for all the text, I will definitely checkout the formatting features next time. Thank You!

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

END RESULT (EXAMPLE)

[SCREENSHOT of CATALOG table EXCEL EXAMPLE (Please Click!, Embedded images not able for me yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uZWs.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please put plain text in your questions. You can get code-like formatting by indenting text four spaces. Please don't use screenshot images to ask your questons.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up a bit more on this StackOverflow, I found a simple Answer. However this only worked after changing the SELECT column header names to each be unique within my tables, therefore avoiding ambiguity errors.

Column names changed within Tables:
Table.Parts (**part_number** column) = ***NO CHANGE***
Table.Inventory (**part_number** column) = "**inv_part**"

```
CREATE TABLE Catalog
 AS (SELECT part_number, SUM(Qty) Qty
     FROM Parts, Inventory
     WHERE part_number = inv_part GROUP BY inv_part);
```

This Pulled all my Part Numbers that had Quantity in my Inventory Table all while Adding the total values for duplicate entries.

> If someone could still point me in the right direction to auto update
>   this new Table, I'd appreciate it.
>
> -I was looking at Triggers, not sure if that would be the right approach. I hope answering my own question doesn't close this post.
>   Thanks again!